# Prove that for every prime $p > 100$ and every integer $r$ $\exists a, b$ such that $p \mid a^2 + b^5 - r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that for every prime $p > 100$ and every integer $r$ $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \mid a^2 + b^5 - r$

Preferably without using Jacobi sums, I have already seen a solution using that.

Comment: evidently the only prime for which any $r$ cannot be expressed is $p=11,$ there is no solution to $a^2 + b^5 \equiv 7 \pmod {11}.$ I suppose some counting argument gets a little easier for $p > 100.$ Note that this is trivial unless $p \equiv 1 \pmod 5,$ as everything is a fifth power and we can just ignore $a^2.$